# output raster size in zonal statistics

Tags: raster

Using zonal statistics, my input raster is 1*1 and input value raster is 10*10. I was hoping the output raster will be 1*1 but it is 10*10. What is the error here ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! Please [take the Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to get some pointers on how to ask a well received question. For one: we will not be able to help you if you do not include the name and version of the software you are using as well as the exact procedure to calculate the zonal statistics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Zonal Statistics tool in the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension, then the output raster cell size defaults to the coarsest resolution of the input rasters.  You can change this by selecting 'Environments' from the bottom of the Zonal Statistics tool dialog, then selecting  the 'Raster Analysis' section.  The first drop-down will allow you to change your output cell size to 'minimum of inputs'.  This is useful for maintaining a consistent resolution between rasters in your project, but be aware that this increased resolution will not lead to more information being contained in your output, as the statistics for your 1x1 output cells will all be derived from the same 10x10 value cell it overlaps (i.e. you will have 100 cells with the same value instead of 1 10x10 cell).

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I cannot change the environment while doing it using model builder.

Comment: No problem - if this solved you issue, you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer.